# Static x-axis with datetime type column

Tags: javascript, django, google-visualization

I set my chart's column type to datetime and it has added un-necessary dates with large space in between in the x-axis, and reduced the size of the columns to almost invisible.

[screen shot 1]:

[image]

If I change the column to String type, and replace the data with String, then I get this [screen shot 2]:

[image]

Is there an option that would exclude the distance associated with time in x-axis? Basically, I want the x-axis to behave as if it was still a string type. I want static distance between the bars and keep the datetime type because I need it to set filters.

Anyone has any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dates simply don't work well with `ColumnChart`

you can try adjusting `bar.groupWidth` and other options but never seems to work

in the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes), they mention they've...

> Added options to specify bar.width, bar.gap, bar.group.width (was bar.groupWidth) and bar.group.gap.

none of these seem to do the trick

using a *Material* chart gets a little closer, but still displays many dates in between columns

but if you like the look of the chart with `type: 'string'`

you can use a `DataView` to draw the chart, based on the values from the filter

the following snippet creates a `DataView`,
converts the first column to `'string'`,
and filters the data based on the values chosen in the filter

```
  var range = slider.getState();

  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(slider.getDataTable());

  dataView.setColumns([{
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 0,
    type: 'string'
  }, 1, 2]);

  dataView.setRows(dataTable.getFilteredRows([{
    column: 0,
    minValue: range.lowValue,
    maxValue: range.highValue
  }]));
```

see following working snippet, the chart is drawn when the slider is `'ready'` and on `'statechange'`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'Date', type: 'date'},
        {label: '+', type: 'number'},
        {label: '-', type: 'number'},
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 2, 13)}, {v: null}, {v: -100}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 3, 18)}, {v: 50}, {v: null}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 4, 21)}, {v: 50}, {v: null}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 5, 20)}, {v: null}, {v: -200}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 6, 23)}, {v: 50}, {v: null}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 7, 12)}, {v: 100}, {v: null}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 8, 28)}, {v: 200}, {v: null}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 8, 28)}, {v: null}, {v: -1000}]}
      ]
    });

    var options = {
      title: 'Transaction Chart'
    };

    var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      controlType: 'DateRangeFilter',
      containerId: 'filter_div',
      dataTable: dataTable,
      options: {
        filterColumnIndex: 0,
        ui: {
          format: {pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}
        }
      }
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(slider, 'ready', drawChart);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(slider, 'statechange', drawChart);

    slider.draw();

    function drawChart() {
      var range = slider.getState();

      var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(slider.getDataTable());
      dataView.setColumns([{
        calc: 'stringify',
        sourceColumn: 0,
        type: 'string'
      }, 1, 2]);
      dataView.setRows(dataTable.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 0,
        minValue: range.lowValue,
        maxValue: range.highValue
      }]));

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(dataView, options);
    }
  },
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="filter_div"></div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to move this to chat? The problem with this method is, as awesome as it is, I'm sending data to template using json. The data is an array, and I loop through that array and convert the first column to JS date format. I place the array in rows directly. In the above method, do I have to surround the data in the array with parentheses and other formatting??

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771) which shows how to build JSON, specifically with a date column, that google will accept -- formatting the data as in the above answer, allows you to create the `DataTable` directly from the JSON, without using `JSON.parse` or `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` -- when feeding `DataTable`, the JSON can be a string or an actual JSON object -- see the [`DataTable` contrcutor method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#constructor_1) for more...