# Google Chart draw Trendlines with date on x axis

Tags: jquery, ajax, charts, google-visualization

I need to draw a Google Line Chart with Trendlines, but I use an Ajax request to get data to put inside it

In the ajax file, I insert in one array the elements of the graphic and after I convert it in JSON like that:

```
$reply= json_encode($array);
echo $reply;
```

This is the content of my ajax reply:

```
reply = [
    ["Periodo","Rome","Milan","Test"],
    ["20160830",1,2,3],
    ["20160831",2,3,6],
    ["20160901",2,3,20],
    ["20160902",20,30,12]
  ];
```

In my program I populate the graphic like that:

```
var replyJSON = JSON.parse(reply);
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(replyJSON);
```

This is a similar example of what I have and what I would to do, but here I can't replicate the ajax call: http://jsfiddle.net/roby492/srrrn9sa/384/

I need to get reply JSON, convert the string of date in jquery date to show correctly the trendlines.

How can I do this? Or how Can I send by Ajax the JSON with date instead of a string?

Thank you.
Roberto R.

Answer (score 4):

take a look at this [php to google chart via ajax example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771)

recommend similar setup here

the example builds JSON that is acceptable by google

which allows creation of the `DataTable`, *directly* from the JSON

following is a snippet from that answer, that builds the JSON

```
$rows = array();
$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Time', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Wind_Speed', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Wind_Gust', 'type' => 'number')
);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlResult)) {
  $temp = array();
  $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $row['Time']);
  $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $row['Wind_Speed']);
  $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $row['Wind_Gust']);
  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

echo json_encode($table);
```

to use an actual Date column in the JSON, gets a little tricky

primarily because month numbers in JavaScript are zero-based, unlike php

so if you format a Date in php, need to reduce the month number by 1

which makes for a lengthy format statement

to pass a date in JSON, you can use the following format, note that it is passed as a string...

`"Date(2016, 8, 28, 15, 34, 40)"` --> which equates to today's date
again, the month is zero-based (8 = September)

so to build a date in this format in php, you can use the following...

```
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date2 = "Date(".date_format($date1, 'Y').", ".((int) date_format($date1, 'm') - 1).", ".date_format($date1, 'd').", ".date_format($date1, 'H').", ".date_format($date1, 'i').", ".date_format($date1, 's').")";
```

which produces the `"Date(...)"` shown above

adjusting the snippet from the other answer to include a Date column, might look something like this...

```
$rows = array();
$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'date'),
    array('label' => 'Wind_Speed', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Wind_Gust', 'type' => 'number')
);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlResult)) {
  $date1 = $row['Date'];
  $date2 = "Date(".date_format($date1, 'Y').", ".((int) date_format($date1, 'm') - 1).", ".date_format($date1, 'd').", ".date_format($date1, 'H').", ".date_format($date1, 'i').", ".date_format($date1, 's').")";

  $temp = array();
  $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $date2);
  $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $row['Wind_Speed']);
  $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $row['Wind_Gust']);
  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

echo json_encode($table);
```

getting the above results via ajax from php, you can create the table directly

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(reply);
```

no need to parse the JSON or use `arrayToDataTable`

Comment: This works fine, but I had solve in another way this time: insert into the JSON the date like this "/date(timestamp in ms)/" and parse it with a function to convert string in date object.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample! date_create() was useful in my case: $date1 = date_create($row['Date'])