# Export php array to json with a specific structure (google charts)

Tags: php, json, sqlite, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to use the google charts api to present power (watt) over time. I have a sqlite database in which i store my data. A php script then gathers the data and outputs it into a json file. For the charts to work i need to keep a specific structure. Whenever i run the phpscript the json file gets overwritten with the new data. I need help with the php script to always output the data according to googles parameters.

I'm aiming to end up with an area chart that plots power on the y axis and the datestamps on the x axis. 
I've read theese documents in googles documentation but i can't figure out how to output the data the way they do.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam

```
while ($res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $voltage[] = $res['voltage'];
        $current[] = $res['current'];
        $datestamp[] = $res['datestamp'];
}

$unixtimestamp = array();
foreach ($datestamp as $nebulosa){
        $unixtimestamp[] = strtotime($nebulosa);
}

$power = array();
foreach ($voltage as $key => $door){
        $power[] = $door * $current[$key];
}

//echo "<pre>", print_r($power, true), "</pre>";

$fp = fopen('data.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($power));
fwrite($fp, json_encode($datestamp));
fclose($fp);
```

The json file has this format after running the php script.

```
[3.468,5]["2016-10-14 14:56:22","2016-10-14 14:56:23"]
```

Comment: If you write two JSON strings to a file, the result is not valid JSON. You need to combine them into a single array, and encode that.

Comment: The documentation you linked to shows `cols` and `rows` elements of the array. You don't seem to have made any attempt to put those in your data.

Comment: @Barmar You are absolutely right. I haven't tried to add the cols and rows yet since i have no idea of where to begin :)

Comment: How would i move forward to combine my arrays in to a single array? Do i use the datestamp as the index and the power as the "data", for example?

Comment: `json_encode(array('col' => $col_info, 'rows' => $row_data))`. The datestamps would be the column labels. The power would be in the `v` properties of the row data.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your answer! The code that you posted seems to work. I switched your variables $col_info and $row_data to my own. When i look at the documentation the json file should look something like this:
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]}

Where would i enter the c, v, and f values?
I also miss the "type", i want number and date as my type how would i implement this?

Comment: Something like `$datestamp[] = array('v' => $res['datestamp'])`. Then you would do `$row_data['c'] = $datestamp`.

Comment: This is just a matter of building up nested arrays with the values you want, according to the structure in the documentation. Just work it out step by step and you should figure it out -- that's what programming is all about. I could write the whole thing in an answer, but then you'll not learn anything.

Comment: @Barmar you're right i'll do some reading on multidimensional arrays and see if i can get it together. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771) _should_ help...