# Converting mysql datetime in php to use in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, datetime, google-visualization

I try to convert mysql datetimes from the mysql function now() into datetimes that i can use for  javascript because i making a google chart and i want to do this in php because i put al the data there in an array.

```
$date = date("Y/m/d",strtotime($row["DateTime"]));
array_push($products,[$date, intval($row["RPI1"]), `intval($row["RPI2"]),
intval($row["RPI3"]), intval($row["RPI4"]), intval($row["RPI5"]),
intval($row["RPI6"]), intval($row["RPI7"]), intval($row["RPI8"])]);`
```

When i do print_r of the array i can see that the conversion was successful.

```
print_r($products);
//Result: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2016/12/30 [1] => 8 [2] => 11 [3] => 26 [4] => 6 [5] => 14 [6] => 15 [7] => 33 [8] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2016/12/30 [1] ...
```

But when i put the array inside the graphic i didn't get any result does anybody know how i can solve this?

```
   // Define the chart to be drawn.
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('date', 'Datetime');
   data.addColumn('number', 'RPI1');
   data.addColumn('number', 'RPI2');
   data.addColumn('number', 'RPI3');
   data.addColumn('number', 'RPI4');
   data.addColumn('number', 'RPI5');
   data.addColumn('number', 'RPI6');
   data.addColumn('number', 'RPI7');
   data.addColumn('number', 'RPI8');
   var products = <?php echo json_encode( $products ) ?>;
   data.addRows(products);

   // Set chart options
   var options = {'title' : 'Average Temperatures of Cities',
      hAxis: {
         title: 'Month'
      },
      vAxis: {
         title: 'Temperature'
      },   
      'width':550,
      'height':400,
      curveType: 'function'
   };

   // Instantiate and draw the chart.
   var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('container'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
}
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

***EDIT:***
I have now changed my code so that

```
//PHP
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $datetimeArr = explode(' ', $row['DateTime']); // split into date and time segments
            $dateArr = explode('-', $datetimeArr[0]); // split date into year, month, day
            $timeArr = explode(':', $datetimeArr[1]); // split time into hour, minute, second

        $year = (int) $dateArr[0];
        $month = ((int) $dateArr[1]) - 1; // javascript uses a 0-based index for months, so we have to subtract 1
        $day = (int) $dateArr[2];
        $hour = (int) $timeArr[0];
        $minute = (int) $timeArr[1];
        $second = (int) $timeArr[2];
        $date = "Date($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second)";
        array_push($products, [$date, intval($row["RPI1"]), intval($row["RPI2"]), intval($row["RPI3"]), intval($row["RPI4"]), intval($row["RPI5"]), intval($row["RPI6"]), intval($row["RPI7"]), intval($row["RPI8"])]);
    }
    $conn->close();
    // encode the table as JSON
    $jsonTable = json_encode($products, true);
    // return the JSON data
    echo $jsonTable;
 print_r($jsonTable)
?>
```

Now with the print_r of the variable jsontable i get result like this inside the browser

```
//[["Date(2016, 11, 30, 12, 42, 17)",8,11,26,6,14,15,33,0],["Date(2016, 11, 30, 12, 42, 27)",19,16,28,19,9,32,28,11],["Date(2016, 11, 30, 12, 42, 37)",25,10,1,26,31,32,31,14],["Date(2016, 11, 30, 12, 42, 48)",19,4,21,18,31,24,34,21],["Date(2016, 11, 30, 12, 42, 58)",9,6,29,13,8,15,32,1],["Date(2016, 11, 30, 12, 43, 8)",28,30,2,3,2,0,10,2],["Date(2016, 11, 30, 12, 43, 19)",21,18,18,3,15,0,28,16],["Date(2016, 11, 30, 12, 43, 30)",27,27,3,21,3,27,12,34],["Date(2016, 11, 30, 12, 43, 40)",25,9,8,2,4,12,12,26],["Date(2016, 11, 30, 12, 43, 50)",16,15,17,14,8,27,33,11],...
```

But i still not working in the google chart...

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771) will show how to format date in php for google chart