# How to use The Date and Time in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

I am trying to use a MySQL TimeStamp for the X Axis on a Scatter graph using Google Charts. Currently, the only way I have managed to get the graph displaying it using the strtotime() Function. This confuses the graph or me as strtotime() Function shows a number of seconds from 1st Jan 1970.

new Date(2017-03-07 02:03:12)] YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:SS this is the format of the date coming from my timestamp if I leave it like this then I get the error. only if I change the time to the strtotime() this works. But the Graph does not show the time properly. Is there another way to display the timestamp. As the Documentation on google does not make much sense.

```
       function drawChart() {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Distance');
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'time');

    data.addRows([


    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM iot_sensors WHERE Sensor_ID ='Ultra_Dist'";
    $execute = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)){

            $date = strtotime($row['Time_Stamp']);

            echo "[".$row['Sensor_1'].", new Date(".$date.")],";

    $Trimmed = trim($row['Time_Stamp']);
    //echo $Trimmed; 

  }
    ?>  
]);

 var options = {
  width: 800,
  height: 500,
  chart: {
    title: 'Frequency of movement by time',
    subtitle: 'Frequency of movement'
  },
  hAxis: {title: 'Distance'},
  vAxis: {title: 'time'}
};
```

This is my code which retrieves the Time_Stamp and other value from my table and puts it in an array for the chart to use.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771) _may_ help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM iot_sensors WHERE Sensor_ID ='Ultra_Dist'";
    $execute = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)){

            $date = ($row['Time_Stamp']);
            $date2 = new DateTime($date);
            $date3 = date_format($date2, 'Y,m,d,H,i,s');

            echo "[new Date(".$date3."),".$row['Sensor_1']."],";  
  }
    ?>
```

Put the date in a new Date() object then reformat it to the accepted format and then echo the date in the array.