# google visualization error in Google gantt Chart

Tags: json, charts, google-visualization, gantt-chart

I need help!!, I'm developing a Google Gantt Chart like google example, but trying to parse from mysql. In the same php page i build the query with json output and then with javascript read it but i get an error in visualization. I validate the json output and it's ok, so dont know where is the error, maybe in how the json is build, thanks and regards.

this is the php:

```
<?php  
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$result = $con->query('SELECT * FROM gantt_tasks');

$rows = array();
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
// Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.
array('label' => 'task_id', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'task_name', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'start_date', 'type' => 'date'),
array('label' => 'end_date', 'type' => 'date'),
array('label' => 'duration', 'type' => 'number'),
array('label' => 'progress', 'type' => 'number'),
array('label' => 'dependencies', 'type' => 'string')
);
/* Extract the information from $result */
foreach($result as $r) {
  $temp = array();
  // Values of the each slice
  $temp[] = array('v' =>  $r['task_id']); 
  $temp[] = array('v' =>  $r['task_name']); 
  $temp[] = array('v' =>  $r['start_date']); 
  $temp[] = array('v' =>  $r['end_date']); 
  $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['duration']); 
  $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['progress']); 
  $temp[] = array('v' =>  $r['dependencies']); 
  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable_act = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable_act;
?>
```

and this is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable_act?>);
  var options = {
      height: 275
    };
  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new 
google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

and this

```
 <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

this is the example in google gantt chart

function drawChart() {

```
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
  data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

  data.addRows([
    ['Research', 'Find sources', null,new Date(2015, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 0, 5), null,  100,  null],
    ['Write', 'Write paper', 'write',null, new Date(2015, 0, 9), daysToMilliseconds(3), 25, 'Research,Outline'],
    ['Cite', 'Create bibliography', 'write',null, new Date(2015, 0, 7), daysToMilliseconds(1), 20, 'Research'],
    ['Complete', 'Hand in paper', 'complete',null, new Date(2015, 0, 10), daysToMilliseconds(1), 0, 'Cite,Write'],
    ['Outline', 'Outline paper', 'write',null, new Date(2015, 0, 6), daysToMilliseconds(1), 100, 'Research']
  ]);
```

the json result:

{"cols":[{"label":"task_id","type":"number"},{"label":"task_name","type":"string"},{"label":"start_date","type":"date"},{"label":"end_date","type":"date"},{"label":"duration","type":"number"},{"label":"progress","type":"number"},{"label":"dependencies","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"a"},{"v":"Impresion"},{"v":"Date(2017, 5, 15)"},{"v":"Date(2017, 5, 20)"},{"v":0},{"v":100},{"v":"0"}]},{"c":[{"v":"b"},{"v":"Acabado manual"},{"v":"Date(2017, 5, 15)"},{"v":"Date(2017, 5, 18)"},{"v":3},{"v":25},{"v":"a"}]},{"c":[{"v":"c"},{"v":"Laminado"},{"v":"Date(2017, 5, 15)"},{"v":"Date(2017, 5, 17)"},{"v":1},{"v":20},{"v":"a"}]},{"c":[{"v":"d"},{"v":"Empaque"},{"v":"Date(2017, 5, 15)"},{"v":"Date(2017, 5, 19)"},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":"c"}]},{"c":[{"v":"e"},{"v":"Corte"},{"v":"Date(2017, 5, 17)"},{"v":"Date(2017, 5, 19)"},{"v":1},{"v":100},{"v":"a"}]}]}

but still not working. and no errors to follow, why? thanks a lot

Comment: please share a sample of the json result --> `<?=$jsonTable_act?>` -- the `'date'` columns [will need to be in a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771)...

Comment: i paste the json result, thanks

Comment: definitely need to change the format of `start_date` and `end_date`, see answer in previous comment, could use formula shown for `$date2`...

Comment: i change the format but no sucess, thanks

Comment: remove the word `new` --> `{"v":"Date(2017, 5, 15)"}`

Comment: i try that also, but nothing, i paste the google example, no idea what is happening o how to debug it

Comment: check for errors in the browser's console -- most press F12