# PHP Date format in array for Google Charts from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, google-visualization

During the loop of the mysql query result, I'm returning a date (yyyy-mm-dd) from my db table. The issue is that I don't know how to format it for Google Charts (line). What's the correct return for the json array?

```
foreach($resultForLine as $rCL) {
    $tempCL = array();
    $tempCL[] = array('v' => (date(Y n j)) $rCL['startDate']);
    $tempCL[] = array('v' => (int) $rCL['Total']);
    $rowsCL[] = array('c' => $tempCL);
}
```

Comment: you would be getting errors here, being undefined constants for `date(Y n j)`.

Comment: Is that supposed to be an attempt at "casting" a string value into a specific date format? It doesn't work this way in PHP. You will need to parse your string value into a unix timestamp first, and then feed that into date, specifying the format in string form as well.

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771)...

Answer (score 0):

You want to parse then output in the desired format. Php make it really easy to parse dates using createFromFormat

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Then you can output in the desired format, or a timestamp. Using format, or getTimestamp.

eg.

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $rCL['startDate']);

$tempCL[] = array('v'=>$date->getTimestamp());