# Google Chart converted date changes to one month later date

Tags: javascript, php, date, google-visualization

I'm recently struggling with Google Charts converting my PHP code to JSON and to be accepted by Google charts Javascript module. By that, I mean that the converting is fine, it works, but somehow when I pass my values as dates it passes a month later data. So instead of 2017.10.24, my last datas are 2017.11.24 but with the same values. I'm suspecting that there is something from when converting the dates because when I pass them as string values they get passed right.

Passing as date values:

```
{
    "cols":[
        {"type":"date","label":"Date","p":{}},
        {"type":"number","label":"Column2"}],
    "rows":[
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-16T23:00:00.000Z"}, {"v":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-10-25T22:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12071}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-10-26T22:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12071}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-10-27T22:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12071}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-10-28T22:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12071}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-10-29T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12071}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-10-31T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12071}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-01T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12071}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-02T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10371}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-03T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10371}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-04T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10371}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-05T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10371}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-06T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10371}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-07T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10371}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-08T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10371}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-09T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10215}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-10T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10215}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-11T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10215}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-12T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10215}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-13T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10215}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-14T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10215}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-15T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":10215}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-16T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12501}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-17T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12501}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-18T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12501}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-19T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12501}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-20T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12501}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-21T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12501}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2017-11-22T23:00:00.000Z"},{"v":12501}]}
    ]}
}
```

Passing as string values:

```
{
    "cols":[
        {"type":"string","label":"Date","p":{}},
        {"type":"number","label":"Columns2"}],
    "rows":[
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,17)"},{"v":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,09,26)"},{"v":12071}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,09,27)"},{"v":12071}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,09,28)"},{"v":12071}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,09,29)"},{"v":12071}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,09,30)"},{"v":12071}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,01)"},{"v":12071}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,02)"},{"v":12071}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,03)"},{"v":10371}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,04)"},{"v":10371}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,05)"},{"v":10371}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,06)"},{"v":10371}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,07)"},{"v":10371}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,08)"},{"v":10371}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,09)"},{"v":10371}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,10)"},{"v":10215}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,11)"},{"v":10215}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,12)"},{"v":10215}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,13)"},{"v":10215}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,14)"},{"v":10215}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,15)"},{"v":10215}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,16)"},{"v":10215}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,17)"},{"v":12501}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,18)"},{"v":12501}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,19)"},{"v":12501}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,20)"},{"v":12501}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,21)"},{"v":12501}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,22)"},{"v":12501}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Date(2017,10,23)"},{"v":12501}]}
    ]
}
```

I assign the values like this:

```
for ($i=$weeks; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $date1 = new DateTime($arraySomething[$i]["date"]);

    $dataArray['rows'][] = array(
        'c' => array (
            array('v' => "Date(".$date1->format("Y,m,d").")"), 
            array('v' => $arraySomething[$i]["property"])
        )
    );

}
```

Does anybody have a clue why does this happen? Also, my first value is somehow another value, it's because of another part of the script, but don't mind that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the month number in javascript is zero-based --> `0=Jan, 1=Feb, 2=Mar, ...`

Comment: [here is a php example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771) you can use to format the date for javascript...