# c.getTimezoneOffset is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-visualization, sql-server-2014

need help with my Google chart. Gettin error "c.getTimezoneOffset is not a function". The Login Credentials are included with wlmXXX.php. Array is working, tested it with "print_r(table).
This is my Chart php file:

```
    <?php
  include ("../server/wlmXXX.php");

  $address = $server.$instance;
  $connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$address;$port;DATABASE=$database";
  $conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass);
  $sql="SELECT TOP (100) CONVERT(char(10), TimeDateStatus,102) AS Date, Space_Used_MB FROM HistoryDB.dbo.SelectInfoDb WHERE DBName = 'LOGATEST' AND TimeDateStatus between dateadd(day,-7,getdate()) and getdate()";
  $rs=odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
  $rows = array();
  $table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
 array(
  'label' => 'Datum',
  'type' => 'datetime'
 ),
 array(
  'label' => 'Größe in GB',
  'type' => 'number'
 )
);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs))
{
  $sub_array = array();
  $sub_array[] =  array(
       "v" => $row["Date"]
      );
 $sub_array[] =  array(
      "v" => $row["Space_Used_MB"]
     );
 $rows[] =  array(
     "c" => $sub_array
    );
}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
print_r($table);
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   function drawChart()
   {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);
    var options = {
     title:'Datenbankwachstum',
     legend:{position:'bottom'},
     chartArea:{width:'95%', height:'65%'}
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
   }
  </script>
  <style>
  .page-wrapper
  {
   width:1000px;
   margin:0 auto;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="page-wrapper">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">Display some Data with google charts</h2>
   <div id="line_chart" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

With this code, the Heading "Display some Data with google charts" is appearing and the array with correct data and this chart error, but nothing else.

Comment: will you please share a sample value of `$row["Date"]`? it should look something like this --> `"Date(2018, 4, 7, 15, 30, 0, 0)"` -- see --> [Dates and Times Using the Date String Representation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#datestring) -- and here is a php example --> [Google Chart draw Trendlines with date on x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771)

Comment: Moving up the print_r($row) into the while loop gives me following back:
Array ( [Date] => 2018-05-01 [Space_Used_MB] => 855615.75 ) Array ( [Date] => 2018-05-05 [Space_Used_MB] => 855708.63 ) Array ( [Date] => 2018-05-04 [Space_Used_MB] => 855702.63 ) ...

Comment: if you want a true date, you'll nee to follow the example i shared, otherwise, you can change the column type to string --> `'type' => 'string'`

Comment: Using String worked for me now. Thank you very much. But now i see my axes and the line are not named right, tryin to solve this tomorrow.