# Google charts working with sample data but not with custom data

Tags: php, mysql, charts, google-visualization, jsfiddle

I'm currently trying to present a bar chart in a PHP, Mysql document and I'm having some issues.

1- the chart works almost fine on fiddle but not on my local machine.
 [Chart on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/castropereira/ezg5vuy2/9/#&togetherjs=U2SztOCStm)

this is my sample code for the chart:

```
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Data');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Valor de Renda');

  data.addRows([
   [new Date( 2010, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2010, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2010, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2010, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2010, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2010, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2010, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2010, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2010, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2010, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2010, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2011, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2011, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2011, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2011, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2011, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2011, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2011, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2011, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2011, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2011, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2011, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2011, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2012, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2012, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2012, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2012, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2012, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2012, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2012, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2012, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2012, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2012, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2012, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2012, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2013, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2013, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2013, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2013, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2013, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2013, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2013, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2013, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2013, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2013, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2013, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2013, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2014, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2014, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2014, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2014, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2014, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2014, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2014, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2014, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2014, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2014, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2014, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2014, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2015, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2015, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2015, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2015, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2015, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2015, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2015, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2015, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2015, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2015, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2015, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2015, 1, 01), 1500], [new Date( 2019, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2019, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2019, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2019, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2019, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2019, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2019, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2019, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2019, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2019, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2019, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2019, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2020, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2020, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2020, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2020, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2020, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2020, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2020, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2020, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2020, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2020, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2020, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2020, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2021, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2021, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2021, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2021, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2021, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2021, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2021, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2021, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2021, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2021, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2021, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2021, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2022, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2022, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2022, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2022, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2022, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2022, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2022, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2022, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2022, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2022, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2022, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2022, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2023, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2023, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2023, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2023, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2023, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2023, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2023, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2023, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2023, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2023, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2023, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2023, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2024, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2024, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2024, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2024, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2024, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2024, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2024, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2024, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2024, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2024, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2024, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2024, 1, 01), 1000], [new Date( 2025, 1, 01), 1000],
  ]);

  var linearOptions = {
  axes: {
        y: {
            all: {
                range: {
                    max: 3000,
                    min: 000
                }
            }
        }
    },
    bars: 'vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    width: 800,
    height: 300
  };


  var linearChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linear_div'));
   linearChart.draw(data, linearOptions);


}
```

2- I've tried using the data as it is showed in fiddle and still nothing appears on the page.

3 -  with the sample data works local, but not when I change to my data

My data is gathered from a Mysql query that i'm "echoing" where i should:

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Data');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Valor de Renda');

  data.addRows([
   <?php echo $listagem ;?>
  ]);

  var linearOptions = {
  axes: {
        y: {
            all: {
                range: {
                    max: 3000,
                    min: 000
                }
            }
        }
    },
    bars: 'vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    width: 800,
    height: 300
  };


  var linearChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linear_div'));
   linearChart.draw(data, linearOptions);


}
```

**UPDATE:**

AS suggested I tried to convert the data into a Json object in my query:

```
$rows = array();
$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Data', 'type' => 'date'),
    array('label' => 'Valor', 'type' => 'number')
);


$query_old_date = "SELECT ContratoFraccaoInicio AS INICIO, ContratoFraccaoFim AS FIM FROM TbContratoFraccao WHERE FkFracao=" . $id_fraccao . " ORDER BY ContratoFraccaoInicio ASC";
$result_old_date = mysqli_query($link, $query_old_date);

while($datas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_old_date)){

    $old_date = $datas['INICIO'];
    $end_date = $datas['FIM'];

$data_inicio = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($old_date));
$data_fim = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date));


$start    = (new DateTime($data_inicio))->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = (new DateTime($data_fim))->modify('first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
   $mes =  $dt->format("Y-m-d");




    $query_valor_mes = "SELECT MAX(Data) AS DATAVALOR FROM TbContratoFracaoPreco WHERE FkFraccao='$id'  and data<='" . $mes . "'";

    $result_valor_mes = mysqli_query($link, $query_valor_mes);

    while($row_valor_mes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_valor_mes)){
        $data_valor = $row_valor_mes['DATAVALOR'];




        $query_obter_valor = " SELECT * FROM TbContratoFracaoPreco WHERE FkFraccao='$id' and data='" . $data_valor . "'";
        $result_obter_valor = mysqli_query($link, $query_obter_valor);

        while($row_renda = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_obter_valor)){

            $rent = $row_renda['ContratoFracaoPreco'];


            $date_year = date('Y', strtotime($mes));
            $date_month = date('m', strtotime($mes))-1;
            $date_day = date('d', strtotime($mes));

            $listing =  "Date(" . $date_year.", " . $date_month .", " . $date_day . ")";


                $temp = array();
  $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $listing);
  $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $rent);
  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);



        };



    };
};
};


$table['rows'] = $rows;

$dados_chart = json_encode($table);
```

And in the chart I have:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Data');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Valor de Renda');
  data.addRows(<?php echo $dados_chart;?>);

  var linearOptions = {
  axes: {
        y: {
            all: {
                range: {
                    max: 3000,
                    min: 000
                }
            }
        }
    },
    bars: 'vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    width: 800,
    height: 300
  };


  var linearChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linear_div'));
   linearChart.draw(data, linearOptions);


}
```

And beside a blank page the only thing I have is this console error:

[image]

Sample result after echo the $dados_chart object:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"Data","type":"date"},{"label":"Valor","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2010, 1, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2010, 2, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2010, 3, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2010, 4, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2010, 5, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2010, 6, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2010, 7, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2010, 8, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2010, 9, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2010, 10, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2010, 11, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 0, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 1, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 2, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 3, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 4, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 5, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 6, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 7, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 8, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 9, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 10, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 11, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 0, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 1, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 2, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 3, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 4, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 5, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 6, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 7, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 8, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 9, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 10, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2012, 11, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 0, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 1, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 2, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 3, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 4, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 5, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 6, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 7, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 8, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 9, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 10, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 11, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 0, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 1, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 2, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 3, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 5, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 6, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 7, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 8, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 9, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 10, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 11, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 0, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 1, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 2, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 3, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 4, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 5, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 6, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 7, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 8, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 9, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 10, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2015, 11, 01)"},{"v":1500}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2019, 0, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2019, 1, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2019, 2, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2019, 3, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2019, 4, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2019, 5, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2019, 6, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2019, 7, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2019, 8, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2019, 9, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2019, 10, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2019, 11, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2020, 0, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2020, 1, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2020, 2, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2020, 3, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2020, 4, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2020, 5, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2020, 6, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2020, 7, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2020, 8, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2020, 9, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2020, 10, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2020, 11, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021, 0, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021, 1, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021, 2, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021, 3, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021, 4, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021, 5, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021, 6, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021, 7, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021, 8, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021, 9, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021, 10, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2021, 11, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022, 0, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022, 1, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022, 2, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022, 3, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022, 4, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022, 5, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022, 6, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022, 7, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022, 8, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022, 9, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022, 10, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022, 11, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2023, 0, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2023, 1, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2023, 2, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2023, 3, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2023, 4, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2023, 5, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2023, 6, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2023, 7, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2023, 8, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2023, 9, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2023, 10, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2023, 11, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2024, 0, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2024, 1, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2024, 2, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2024, 3, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2024, 4, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2024, 5, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2024, 6, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2024, 7, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2024, 8, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2024, 9, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2024, 10, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2024, 11, 01)"},{"v":1000}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2025, 0, 01)"},{"v":1000}]}]}
```

Comment: Have you checked your developer console to see if there's any errors? Is the data that you're placing into $listagem correct?

Comment: @whitehat already updated the post to have what i have when echoing the variable

Comment: @aynber I think it is correct because the one I'm using in fiddle I got from echo on the variable $listagem

Comment: @whitehat done!

Comment: @whitehat another thing that trying to accomplish is to show it as a column chart, and have a list of all the months even if they don't have a value ( this is very useful because in the down line connecting the 2 segment, in reality the house wasn't rented, so it should be 0!

Comment: Do not build your own json. Build an array, then use json_encode to encode it. Also make things easier on yourself and just use properly formatted date strings instead of Date objects.

Comment: @aynber is correct, you won't be able to pass dates from a string using the `new` keyword -- take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771)

Comment: I'll try to discover how to do that! thank you for your support. Any guess why it works on fiddle but not local? @whitehat @aynber?

Comment: No idea. There might be a hint in the developer console, though.

Comment: because in the fiddle, it is not a string but actual code -- right click the page and select "view source" or "view page source" (depending on the browser), you should be able to see the difference.

Comment: @whiteHat just followed your suggestion converting it to a Json Object... Could you please check my latest update?

Comment: Mixing javascript and PHP could be tricky at times, but you need to create a global variable, then store your formatted data into this variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the updated json object,
you can create the data table directly,
without `addColumn` and `addRows`

replace this...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Data');
data.addColumn('number', 'Valor de Renda');
data.addRows(<?php echo $dados_chart;?>);
```

with this...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $dados_chart;?>);
```

Comment: the identified problem was solved... now i think I have one last problem to solve... trying to find a solution! "Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Container is not defined" is what the inspector says, but since the div was working i can't understand what is wrong...

Comment: just solved my last problem with help from this link [https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1420] just had to move the script after the div!