# Google Charts ChartRangeFilter not showing with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization, stock

I've been trying to plot an interactive stock chart for some test data taken from mySQL. Connection was established and data was received with no errors. I'm new to Google Charts so I'm not too sure if the code below was applied correctly.

```
<div class="container">
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['submit-search'])) {
        $ticker = $_GET['ticker'];
        $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $ticker);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$ticker."_dailyadj;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartRangeFilter);

  function drawChartRangeFilter() {

        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'control_div',
          'options': {
            // Filter by the date axis.
            'filterColumnIndex': 1,
            'ui': {
              'chartType': 'LineChart',
              'chartOptions': {
                'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
                'hAxis': {
                    'baselineColor': 'none',
                    'format': 'YYYY-MM-dd',
                    'ticks': [
                        <?php
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                                foreach($result as $row) {
                                    echo "['".$row['Date']."'],";
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                ]
            }
              },
              // Display a single series that shows the closing value of the stock.
              // Thus, this view has two columns: the date (axis) and the stock value (line series).
              'chartView': {
                  'columns': [1, {
                      'type': 'number',
                      'calc': function () {return 0;}
                  }]
              },
              // 1 day in milliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86,400,000
              'minRangeSize': 86400000
            }
          }
          Initial range: 2012-02-09 to 2012-03-20.
          'state': {'range': {'start': new Date(2012, 1, 9), 'end': new Date(2012, 2, 20)}}
        });

        var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'CandlestickChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
          'options': {
            // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
            'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '90%'},
            'hAxis': {'slantedText': false},
            'vAxis': {'viewWindow': {'min': 0, 'max': 2000}},
            'legend': {'position': 'none'}
          }
        });

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Low');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Open');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Close');
        data.addColumn('number', 'High');
        data.addRows([
            <?php
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    foreach($result as $row) {
                        echo "['".$row['Date']."', ".$row['Low'].", ".$row['Open'].", ".$row['Close'].", ".$row['High']."],";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        ])
        }

        dashboard.bind(control, chart);
        dashboard.draw(data);
      }
</script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 915px; height: 500px;"></div>
<div id="dashboard_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
    <table class="columns">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="chart_div" style="width: 915px; height: 300px;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="control_div" style="width: 915px; height: 50px;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have had previous success with the following code, which shows that my data was successfully being implemented on a static chart.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'High'],
        <?php
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                foreach($result as $row) {
                    echo "['".$row['Date']."', ".$row['Low'].", ".$row['Open'].", ".$row['Close'].", ".$row['High']."],";
                }
            }
        ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
      legend:'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

Let me know if there is anything that I should take note with the parameters. This has been bothering me for days :(

Comment: the [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) only works on a _continuous_ x-axis (number, date, datetime or timeofday) -- not on a _discrete_ x-axis (string), which is being used here --> `'".$row['Date']."'`

Comment: @WhiteHat Thank You for the response! Unfortunately, I've tried converting my string to a date but to no avail. I've played around with the format of the php code to accomodate to each format type. I've also tried looking hard at the official docs for the parameters, but I'm unsure if any of my parameters were incorrect.

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752634/google-chart-draw-trendlines-with-date-on-x-axis/39756555#39756555)...

Comment: @WhiteHat Hmm, the 2 answers you had did not work for me. Does Google charts have any limitations on the number of datarows in `new google.visualization.DataTable(responseText);` ?

Comment: not that I'm aware of...