# how to fix this google charts bar chart error

Tags: google-visualization

same data are used to draw line chart and bar chart. it works fine for drawing line. but there is an error for drawing bar chart. the error is "a.getTime is not a function×". any suggestions are appreciated.

here is my code:

```
    datasource.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    datasource.addColumn('number', 'quantity');
    datasource.addColumn('number', 'quantity');
    datasource.addColumn('number', 'quantity');
    for (n = 0; n < tem.length; n++) {
        datasource.addRows([[new Date(tem[n][0]), tem[n][1], tem[n][2], tem[n][3]]]);
    }

*********line chart ***********

    chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    var options = {
            actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
            interpolateNulls: true, //bypass null
            legend: 'none',
            crosshair: { trigger: 'both', opacity: 0.5 }, // Display crosshairs on focus and selection.
            title: 'Company Performance',
            hAxis: { title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: { color: 'red' }, format: "YY.MM.dd", slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 30 },
            vAxis: {
                viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
                viewWindow: {
                    max: maxy,
                    min: 0
                }
            },
            explorer: { axis: 'horizontal', maxZoomOut: 1 } //wheel zoom
        };

   chart.draw(datasource, options);

***********bar chart*************

   chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

   var options = {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            hAxis: { title: 'Number', titleTextStyle: { color: 'red' } },
            vAxis: { minValue: 0 },
            explorer: { axis: 'horizontal', maxZoomOut: 1 }
        };

   chart.draw(datasource, options);*
```

Comment: the first column in the google data table is defined as a `'date'`, however, the value being passed to the first column is a `'string'` -- `'07/07'` -- which causes the error. you can correct by changing the type in the data table to `'string'`

Comment: $data=array(['07/07', 2,null,null],['07/08', 0.3,null,null],['07/09', 1,null,null],['07/10', 2,null,null],['07/11', 2.5,null,null],['07/12', 0.6,null,null],['07/13', 2.2,null,null],['07/14', 12,null,null],['07/15', 11,null,null],['07/16', 2.8,null,null],['07/17', 1,null,null],['07/18', 2,null,null],['07/19', 2,null,null],['07/20', 1,null,null],['07/21', 2,null,null],['07/22', 2,null,null],['07/23', 1,null,null],['07/24', 1,null,null],['07/25', 1,null,null]); The first column is changed to this format '2019,07,02'. and the last 2 columns are assigned a value later.

Comment: it was 'string' and worked. I changed it to Date so that it can be zoomed in by mouse wheel.

Comment: then you will need to pass a date, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771) using php...

Comment: anyway, I changed it to column chart instead of bar chart. it works. Thank you everybody.