# Google Chart, X-Axis and Line won't render in Safari, but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, charts, safari, google-visualization

See this codepen:

https://codepen.io/rblythe/pen/OJOVeXa

In chrome it renders just fine like this:

(Although it does have that weird artifact where it shows a blue line outside of the chart on the right side...not sure if that has anything to do with why it won't work in Safari)

[image: In Chrome]

However, in safari it won't render the line and the x-axis doesn't render either.  It seems like it doesn't accept the data points.

[image: In Safari]

Any ideas?

```
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization0);

function drawVisualization0() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'x');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
    data.addColumn('number', 'Rating');
    data.addRow([new Date('2022-01-28 11:42:50'), null, 2]);
    data.addRow([new Date('2022-01-28 14:42:34'), null, 4]);

    var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
    formatter.format(data, 0);
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart0')).
    draw(data, {
        title: '',
        curveType: 'function',
        vAxis: {
            viewWindow: {min: 1, max: 6},
            textStyle:{color: '#FFFFFF'},
            gridlines: {color:"#404758"}
        },
        hAxis: {
            textStyle:{color: '#FFFFFF'},
            gridlines: {color:"#404758"}
        },
        colors: ['#ADC6FF'],
        backgroundColor: '#272930',
        gridlines: {
            color: "#404758"
        },
        baselineColor: '#404758',
        annotations: {
            style: 'line',
            color: "#FFFFFF",
            gridlines: {color:"#404758"},
            textStyle:{color: '#C4C6D0'}
        },
        chartArea: {
          // leave room for y-axis labels
          width: '94%'
        }
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization1);
```

Comment: every time I've had an issue with safari and google charts, it was due to a date -- try using a different date constructor to see if that solves the issue -- `new Date(2022, 0, 28, 14, 42, 34)`

Comment: Thanks for the idea -- I'm using PHP to construct the data (its outputting from a mysql database) so I'm not 100% sure how to get the date formatted like that, but I'll look into it.

Comment: there is an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771)...

Comment: Thanks!  I tested that date format with static data and it works, so that is definitely the solution.  Ah, makes sense, instead of a single date formatted that way, you would repeat echoing the date for each of the 6 digits and each time ask for just one thing (hour, day, month, whatever).

Comment: I don't see a way to mark your comment as the answer, but it definitely was the right answer, thanks again.